# How to screen record secondary display using Media projection API?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojection

I am building a screen recorder for dual screen android devices.
Using [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-ScreenCapture) example i can successfully record primary screen. but can't find any to record secondary screen. I am using media projection API

Comment: Given the example, I assume that you are using a `SurfaceView` and getting the surface from it, then passing that you your `VirtualDisplay`. Instead you should pass `MediaRecorder.getSurface()` to your `VirtualDisplay`. You can have a look at how I implement in my library - https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder

Comment: Hey thank for the reply, you app works find for single screen device but how to create VirtualDisplay of secondary screen. I cant find any thing where i can pass display id and ask media projection API to record second screen. I am using LG G8x devices for testing.